# Adjusting \Chapter spacing with \titlespacing not working and wraps headings

Tags: titlesec

I would like to remove the default 50pt spacing before a chapter heading, I would like to use the `titlesec`package as I am not comfortable editing latex code.

I have tried the  `\titlespacing` command without success, adding this command also places my chapter heading underneath my chapter number.

Thus my question is twofold - how can I change the chapter spacing using the `titlesec` package and keep my chapter number and chapter name in the same line.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry} %showframe to see page outlines
\geometry{
top=1in,
bottom =1in , 
left=1.2in,
right=0.8in,
}

\usepackage{titlesec} %to remove "chapter 1" text only have 1. Introduction
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\bfseries\huge}
{\thechapter}
{.5em}
{\MakeUppercase}
\titlespacing*{\Chapter}{0pt}{-50pt}{20pt}

\begin{document}

\chapter{First chapter}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works as expected if

1. you use the `block`  style – `display` is for chapter label and chapter title on different lines,
2. in `\titlespacing`, you write the command name as `\chapter` with a lowercase `c`.

   ```
   \documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, oneside]{book}
   \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
   \usepackage[english]{babel}
   \usepackage{lipsum}

   \usepackage[showframe]{geometry} %showframe to see page outlines
   \geometry{top=1in, bottom =1in, left=1.2in, right=0.8in}

   \usepackage{titlesec} %to remove "chapter 1" text only have 1. Introduction
   \titleformat{\chapter}[block]{\bfseries\huge}{\thechapter.}{.5em}{MakeUppercase}
   \titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{*-4}{20pt}

   \begin{document}

   \chapter{First chapter}
   \lipsum

   \end{document}
   ```

[image]